# How to add constraint to a synonym?

Tags: oracle, ddl

I have trouble. I did run that code. Unfortunately, couldn't work.

ORA-00942: table or view doesn't exist.

Help me guys :)

```
ALTER SYNONYM tbs_custchnl
ADD CONSTRAINT uniq_four_unique 
UNIQUE(cif, chid, ch_value, langid) DISABLE NOVALIDATE;
```

**Solution**

---

this is synonym. So, I can't add constraint to synonym. In other words, I can only add constraint to a table or view.

Thanks all! :D

Comment: This code should work, assuming your schema has a view called `tbs_custchnl`. Here is [a working demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33364/1).

Comment: @APC Sorry, this is synonym :D I was mistake

Comment: You can't alter the synonym you need to alter the underlying view.

Comment: @APC I see. thanks man!

Comment: It's not just tables. We can add constraints to a view, albeit only disabled constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query to find out if view exists or not:

```
SELECT * FROM all_objects WHERE object_type IN ('TABLE','VIEW') AND object_name = 'tbs_custchnl'
```

Comment: Sorry, this is synonym :D I was mistake